# How to make character accelerate while pressing arrow key (iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, game-engine

I'm trying to make a game through sprite kit framework, but I'm stuck while trying to make a character move. I want to make the character move (left/right) when I press the key(left/right). While pressing, the character should be speeding up (w/ speed limit), and when I let go of the key, the character should be slowing down to a complete stop. I can't figure out a way to implement this through `SKAction`... Can anyone shed me some light? Thanks.
This is what I've tried so far.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

    if (touchLocation.x > [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame].size.width / 2) {
        _rightPressed = YES;
    } else {
        _leftPressed = YES;
    }

}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    _rightPressed = NO;
    _leftPressed = NO;
    _speedDelimiter = 0;
}
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    // ... code ...


    if (_rightPressed && !_leftPressed && _speedDelimiter < 10) {
        SKAction * moveRight = [SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(10, 0) duration:5];
        [self.player runAction:moveRight];
        _speedDelimiter++;
    } else if (_leftPressed && !_rightPressed && _speedDelimiter < 10){
        SKAction * moveLeft = [SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(-10, 0) duration:5];
        [self.player runAction:moveLeft];
        _speedDelimiter++;
    }
}
```

What I think I should make use of is the `velocity` property in my character's `SKPhysicsBody` property. But I'm not sure.

Comment: This can be achieved very easily by using the physics engine.

Comment: What about with spritekit?

Comment: I mean the physics engine within SpriteKit. Attach SKPhysicsBody to the character and apply force to it.

Comment: /agree, actions aren't exactly suited to what you are trying to do. I guess you could do some ongoing modification of the action's speed property, but I would just position the character manually on every update based on values, or if you don't need super accurate positioning, then just let the physics system handle it all for you.